# swift: Access scene variable in use from controller

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uipangesturerecognizer, skspritenode

I'm working on a game. The game's code is almost entirely in a PlayScene.swift file. However, since I need to recognize pan gestures, I had to put a UIPanGestureRecognizer to my ViewController.swift. As the player drags the screen, I would like to rotate a SpriteNode that is declared and used in the PlayScene.swift. The name of this spriteNode is Tommy, but when I do `PlayScene().rotateTommyLeft()` from the ViewController (which is a custom function of mine located in PlayScene.swift), the function rotateTommyLeft is called, but it doesn't rotate the same sprite that is currently running. It creates a new instance of class PlayScene, creates new SpriteNode tommy and instead rotates that one.

How can I access the SpriteNode tommy from the PlaySceen that is currently running?

Edit: I'm posting the parts of code so we can solve out problem regarding storing the scene and transferring it between other classes.

At the top of my GameScene class, I declared variable storedPlayScene to store the scene in which the gaming occurs.

`var storedPlayScene = PlayScene()`

then, I create the scene and present it when play button is pressed (also in GameScene class)

```
var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
                let skView = self.view as SKView
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                scene.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 106/255.0, green: 180/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

                storedPlayScene = scene

                skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Now the surprising part occurs when I try to obtain two variables belonging to PlayScene class, from the ViewController class.

When I write this in the ViewController class

`var rotation = GameScene().getStoredPlayScene().tommy.zRotation` I obtain the correct zRotation.
However, when I write this in the same ViewController class `var position = GameScene().getStoredPlayScene().getPos()` the data is incorrect. It says that the position is (0,0).

I have problem figuring out why the position is incorrect while the zRotation is good.

Comment: When/where are you creating the `PlayScene` instance that is being used? You'll need to store a reference to that instance and use that reference to call `playScene.rotateTommyLeft()`.

Comment: Thank you. I found the code. It is being created in a previous scene called GameScene. How exactly do I store it so I can access it from the controller too? I tried storing it in NSUserDefaults but I can't retrieve it. Is there any other variable you recommend storing it in?

Comment: _Don't use NSUserDefaults for this, that's not what it's for._ Without seeing your code and/or knowing how your project is laid out it's hard to say exactly what you should do. But, in general, it sounds like `PlayScene` should be a [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_368) on `GameScene` which should be  a property on your view controller. Then you'd access `PlayScene` from your view controller with something like `self.gameScene.playScene`.

Comment: Ok, I created a variable storing the PlayScene class but I'm having partial problem. Could you please look at the edit?

Comment: Couple things: 1. it should be `var storedPlayScene: PlayScene!`, when you use `... = PlayScene()` you're creating a new instance, which is not what you want there. 2. `var rotation = GameScene()...` is creating a new instance of `GameScene` which is also not what you want. You should have something similar to `storedPlayScene` in your view controller for your `GameScene`, `storedGameScene` or something.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the problems in code and that made it work perfectly. If you could just write short description of your answer as an answer, you would gain credit for your help. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `PlayScene().rotateTommyLeft()`, you're creating a new instance of `PlayScene` and not accessing the `playScene` that's currently running in your game. So, you need to store `playScene` somewhere so that you can access it. Since you're creating `playScene` inside `gameScene`, the `GameScene` class is a good place to put add a property for `playScene`.

***Side note:** You mentioned trying to store it in NSUserDefaults in the comments. That's not only not going to work, but that's not what NSUserDefaults is for. NSUserDefaults is designed for simple preferences and not much else. You might store the last name they used for their high score, or maybe what level they're currently on, but usually not things that are much more complex than that.*

Now that we have a property for `playScene` in `gameScene`, you need to be able to access it from your view controller. To do that, you're going to need to be able to access `gameScene` from your view controller. So, just like you added a `playScene` property to `gameScene`, add a `gameScene` property to your view controller. Once that is in place and set correctly, you'll be able to access the original method you were trying to call: `self.gameScene.playScene.rotateTommyLeft()`

Re: rotation and position in your edit. You're doing the same thing there: you're creating a new instance of `GameScene` on each call. If you change that to use the properties we created above, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect and detailed answer that solved my problem.